# How do I serve a website only to the local network with the caddy docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, caddy

I'm trying to get the Caddy docker container to serve a website locally.

I use nginx (also container, the linuxserver/swag) for serving all my services externally, but have two different websites I want to serve, and have seen that trying to serve both in nginx can cause a whole range of issues (mostly security, as far as I could gather, but they didn't go into details).

One is already set up within nginx, so I thought I'd take the opportunity to try Caddy for serving the second locally, and still using nginx to access it from the outside.

But no matter how I try, I can't even access the (Caddy) website from my local IP.

In my docker-compose for I have (among a bunch of other services served through nginx at DOMAIN1 subdomains):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  swag:
    image: linuxserver/swag
    container_name: swag
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/docker/swag/config:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    ports:
      - "10.0.30.21:80:80"
      - "10.0.30.21:443:443"
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1004
      - EMAIL=REDACTED
      - TZ=REDATCTED
      - URL=DOMAIN1.com
      - SUBDOMAINS=list,of,sub,domains,used,on,first,domain
      - DHLEVEL=4096
      - VALIDATION=http
      - EXTRA_DOMAINS=DOMAIN2.COM
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.11.0.2
  caddy:
    image: caddy:latest
    container_name: caddy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "10.0.30.21:8988:80"
      - "10.0.30.21:8989:443"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/docker/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - /mnt/data/docker/caddy/site:/srv
      - /mnt/data/docker/caddy:/data
      - /mnt/data/docker/caddy:/config
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.11.0.80

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.11.0.0/24
```

I've tried various Caddyfile, having the actual website files (in the `/site` directory, referencing in Caddyfile as `root * /site`) or just a minimal:

```
localhost

respond "Hello, world!"
```

Regardless, if I navigate to the IP:PORT that I think should be exposed (as per the docker-compose.yaml file, `10.0.30.21:8988`), I just get redirected to `10.0.30.21` and get served the webpage I have set up in nginx. It works fine for other services running from the same docker-compose, e.g. `10.0.30.21:8123` serves the Home Assistant web UI, so my guess is that it's a Caddy (or Caddy-in-docker) setup issue.

For now, the nginx webpage is served at DOMAIN2.COM, and I eventually want the Caddy website to show at DOMAIN1.COM, since related services (nextcloud, home assistant, dokuwiki, etc.) are at SUB.DOMAIN1.COM. But first thing is to get Caddy to serve locally.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not really sure what.